# Prevent Visual Studio JSX behaviour with React component

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, jsx

I'm using Visual Studio to build a React Native app. I also installed Prettier to improve the syntax.

But every time I add a component with several property it goes to the next line. How could I prevent that and keep my component inline?

[image]

PS: I already tried to increase the "print width" in Prettier and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should check [`jsx-max-props-per-line`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-max-props-per-line.md) `eslint` rule.

You can only set that rule using `ESlint`, prettier doesn't give you that option.

So, what you need to do is use `eslint` with `prettier` and `prettier` will format looking at your `eslint` rules.

Go to `File` => `Preferences` => `Settings` and in the `Prettier` extension, mark `Eslint Integration`.

[image]

You will need to `npm i -D` for `babel-eslint`, `eslint` and `eslint-plugin-react` (wich have the rule you want).

And add the rule of `jsx-max-props-per-line` with the number of props you want to be inline.

If you have problem configuring `ESlint`, just google how to add `ESlint` with React Native, there is alot of tutorials and it's a very important and usefull thing to learn.